# Google Scripts - Reply with new subject

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the reply(body, options) method of the GmailMessage class. I want to add some information to the subject of the incoming mail before sending it back. I wrote this:

```
function submitReply(message, ref) {

  var mSubj = message.getSubject() + " [ref:" + ref + "]";
  var mBody = "This is the new body";

  message.reply(mBody, {
    subject: mSubj
  });
};
```

When I debug, the mSubj string is as expected but the reply is sent with the old subject.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Charles

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function submitReply(message, ref) {

  var mSubj = message.getSubject() + " [ref:" + ref + "]";
  var mBody = "This is the new body";

  message.reply(mBody, {subject: mSubj.toString()});
};
```

I don't really have a way to test that at the moment, I was just looking over the documentation for the message class (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#reply(String,Object)).  Since it's looking for a string, you might want to convert your object to a string.  If you can't .toString() that, then I'd try this:

```
function submitReply(message, ref) {

     var mBody = "This is the new body";

  message.reply(mBody, {subject: message.getSubject() +" [ref:" +ref +"]"});
};
```

Comment: The debugger does see the mSubj variable as a string within the options object. I tried both suggestions anywat and the results are the same.